# Getting the first paragraph of Wikipedia's article using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jquery, jsoup, wikipedia

I'm trying to get the first paragraph of a Wikipedia's article using this code:

```
public String getText(){
    try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel").get();
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
        Element firstParagraph = paragraphs.first();
        return firstParagraph.text();
    }
    catch (IOException e){return "Failed";}
}
```

This is the simplest way of all the ways I have found in threads here on StackOverflow.

I don't get the first paragraph, all I get is this part only:
[image: The part I get from jsoup]

But I want to get this part: [image: first paragraph on Wikipedia]

How can I use it properly?
I'm looking for a general solution...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on the content of the page.
For example, you gave a Wikipedia article and found out that the first paragraph (i.e. - with `<p> tag`) is the coordinates of the country and not the actual first paragraph about it.
This is due to a Wikipedia template for describing countries.

There are a lot of templates out there - for countries, for companies, for personalities etc.
Each subject as a certain template with different outline so it will be difficult to assist you and give you a general answer that would help you will future scenarios.

With specific reference to your question, you are able to exclude the coordinates and get the real first paragraph on the page.
Your code should be:

```
public String getText(){
    try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel").get();
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p:not(:has(#coordinates))");
        Element firstParagraph = paragraphs.first();
        return firstParagraph.text();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        return "Failed";
    }
}
```

By looking at the source code you are able to notice that the coordinates appear in a `<p> tag` (that is why you got this result, to begin with) and inside that tag, there is another `<span> tag`  with the id name of "coordinates". Since you want to remove the coordinates from the results you can use [`jsoup pseudo selectors`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) to get the desired content only.

---

Since it is difficult to answer in a general way to these kinds of question, from the reasons listed above, I would like to add few tips for some further usage:

1. It is recommended to take a very close look at the source code of
   the page you're dealing with and examine all the tags. That way you are
   able to locate some possible problems (like the one that apears in this very question) and consider these factors when you write the code that
   extracts the wanted parts of the page.
2. Check your list of elements after you execute your `CSS Query` in `jsoup`. You can do it either by code or by checking the query on the [try-jsoup site](https://try.jsoup.org/). You can enter [your query](https://try.jsoup.org/~N121eu3qABu0Icc3syO_mL7TfzU) and see the list of elements. That way you might realize that the result is not what you were expecting. Sometimes it wouldn't be as easy as it was in this case, and you might use the list of elements to change your code (say, for example, using `Element firstParagraph = paragraphs.get(1);` instead of using `Element firstParagraph = paragraphs.first();` in your code). You can then test [your newly improved `CSS Query`](https://try.jsoup.org/~jcllGew0OicJkVhCDhNvUdZQceU) and see if that works for you.
3. It is helpful to be familiar with the different selectors `jsoup` has to offer.
   This will make your work easier.

Hope that helps!